# Creating Static Meshes in For Loop using C++ with unreal engine

Tags: c++, for-loop, instantiation, spawning, unreal-engine5

**this is the fix at top**
use this to create a string that Static Mesh Object can accept as a unique identifier so the engine doesn't crash

```
FName name = *FString::Printf(TEXT("Sphere %i"), i);
```

I want to use a for Loop to create static meshes that I can reference later and link to other events over OSC.  I am having a problem figuring out how to name the instances using the CreateDefaultSubobject.

I get this error when Compiling my code:

```
S:\UnrealEngine\CPP_LEARNING\ShaderShootEm_000\Source\ShaderShootEm_000\FlowSphere.cpp(19): error C4456: declaration of 'i' hides previous local declaration 
S:\UnrealEngine\CPP_LEARNING\ShaderShootEm_000\Source\ShaderShootEm_000\FlowSphere.cpp(18): note: see declaration of 'i' 
S:\UnrealEngine\CPP_LEARNING\ShaderShootEm_000\Source\ShaderShootEm_000\FlowSphere.cpp(23): error C4800: Implicit conversion from 'int32' to bool. Possible information loss 
S:\UnrealEngine\CPP_LEARNING\ShaderShootEm_000\Source\ShaderShootEm_000\FlowSphere.cpp(23): note: consider using explicit cast or comparison to 0 to avoid this warning 
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.0\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\Platform.h(998): note: see declaration of 'int32'
```

**This is the Code**

```
RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");
FVector CurrentLocation = GetActorLocation();
StaticMeshes.Init(NULL,10);
float distance = 0;
int32 i = 0;
 for(int32 i= 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    FString Number = FString::FromInt(i);
    distance *= i * 100;
    StaticMeshes[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Number %i"),i );
    StaticMeshes[i]->SetRelativeLocation(CurrentLocation + FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, distance));
    StaticMeshes[i]->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
 }
```

thanks for any help in advance~

Comment: 1) Your `int32 i` index of the loop is hiding the `int32 i` defined just before the loop. 2) It seems like `CreateDefaultSubobject` expects a `bool` param and you pass it `i` which is an `int32`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the name of each instance using the TEXT macro...  I want to use the i to populate the %i value in the TEXT macro.

Comment: if I don't change the name while creating the sub object unreal crashes and says I have a subobject with that name already.

Comment: You can use somethine like: `std::string name = "Number" + std::to_string(i);` to get a string with a filename. You can try to pass it to `CreateDefaultSubobject` (or convert to another string format if needed). In addition you have to supply  `CreateDefaultSubobject` with a `bool bTransient` param. See: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject./UObject/CreateDefaultSubobject/2/

Comment: `RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");
 FVector CurrentLocation = GetActorLocation();
 StaticMeshes.Init(NULL,10);
 float distance = 0;
 // int32 i = 0;
  for(int32 i= 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  FString Number = FString::FromInt(i);
  distance *= i * 100;
  StaticMeshes[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT(Number));
  StaticMeshes[i]->SetRelativeLocation(CurrentLocation + FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, distance));
  StaticMeshes[i]->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
  }`    yields result "Cannot resolve symbol 'LNumber'" in the text macro box

Comment: I'm not sure what type of string I need to convert it to, I've tried a few so far.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Unreal in general and the method `CreateDefaultSubobject` in particular. Just tried to decipher the maning of the error messages you posted.